# Building a recommendation engine for a webapp (Rails + MySQL + ?) -- where to start

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, algorithm, r, recommendation-engine

I'd like to build a recommendation engine to support a web app which is running on Rails and has its data stored in MySQL... something along the lines where users click on things and their feedback updates the database, which then is processed in some sort of realtime-esque fashion.  Order of magnitude I'm thinking probably 10s of interactions a second across all users; 1M datapoints a day.

My question is how do I structure and handle analysis such that things can be quickly processed.  Utilizing what I already know, I can use some flavor of Ruby and R (RServe, RSRuby) to run SVD/clustering/ensemble/whatevermodels on the existing dataset, and update the model/formulas via sampling every so often, but that seems like a really clunky way to do things.  What is a better way of doing this?  Running the math directly in MySQL? Using some cool Ruby library that has great math functions?  Use an off-the-shelf recommendation engine package?

(I have a distinct lack of awareness in what's out there, despite looking at all the "similar questions" links suggested.  Sweet irony. :( )

PS: My background: numbers guy with a few years of R, but entirely for static/offline data.  Newbie programmer in Python, Rails, etc., but I can work on that front.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you really need realtime?

I found that most of these "realtime" cases usually don't really require true realtime but can be done in the background.
Assuming a web-shop where you want to give your customer recommendations on his past sales on maybe on the current selected item (related items other people bought with this one) you could simply precalculate that data in set intervals.

For cases like the one described above I would suggest you use a Rake task to do the heavy lifting (recommendations on past sales is not really something that changes right during the session - and recommendations on related items is also fairly static).

So I would calculate those during a Cron job or some other recurring task that is asynchronous to your Web-Application while you serve the resulting (precomputed) data to active users.
That way you also get a bit more flexibility on the complexity of your calculations since you can run longer than the web requestion should take at maximum.

A sample rake task would look like this:

```
task :calculate_recommendations => :environment do
  // do your calculation
  // you have full access to ActiveRecord here
end
```

(Make sure to include the `:environment`otherwise Rake will not load the Database connections for you.

How do you do the calculation is up to you then, but I would suggest you look at Gems like [Recommendify](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/projects/recommendify) to see what libraries they are using to calculate the recommendations. Maybe that is of help to you.

Also in the [RubyToolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/) there is a [Recommender-Engine category](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Recommendation_Engines) that lists a few gems that are similar and may give you pointers on the right direction.

Comment: Yeah I've been thinking about real time w/ tradeoffs (probably via a sampling method with weights on time) vs Cron jobs every so often on another server.  I'll need to read up on Rails to figure that out instead.

As for recommender-engine stuff... I'll probably look for some flavor of Ruby shell of R if performance is not horrid; the rec-engine gems don't seem to cover all the things I want to do, but I'll need to take a closer look at everything.

Comment: Accepted your answer; the Ruby recommendation libraries that I've found are pretty terrible though (compared to similar offerings in R).  I'll probably use RRuby for now and see if there's anything better.